# Agregar archivos apartir de un icono personalizado

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, bootstrap

Tengo la siguiente vista hecha con bootstrap donde he colocado una imagen svg de un camara para poder al momento de darle click subir una imagen. ¿Como podria agregarle el comportamiento que tiene un input file en ese icono al momento de darle click?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de mi vista:

```
<div class="card-header bg-success">
                    Completada
                    @if($avance == 100)
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="21" height="21" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-camera ml-1" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path d="M15 12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h1.172a3 3 0 0 0 2.12-.879l.83-.828A1 1 0 0 1 6.827 3h2.344a1 1 0 0 1 .707.293l.828.828A3 3 0 0 0 12.828 5H14a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v6zM2 4a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v6a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V6a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-1.172a2 2 0 0 1-1.414-.586l-.828-.828A2 2 0 0 0 9.172 2H6.828a2 2 0 0 0-1.414.586l-.828.828A2 2 0 0 1 3.172 4H2z" />
                            <path d="M8 11a2.5 2.5 0 1 1 0-5 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 0 5zm0 1a3.5 3.5 0 1 0 0-7 3.5 3.5 0 0 0 0 7zM3 6.5a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0z" />
                        </svg>
                    @endif                    
                </div>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.- Creando el input dinámicamente**

Con javascript se crea un elemento `input` y se agrega al DOM

```js
function selectFile(){
  const inputFile = document.createElement("input");
  inputFile.type="file";
  inputFile.style.opacity=0;
  document.body.appendChild(inputFile);
  inputFile.onchange = (e) =>{
   if(e.target.files){
       nameFile.innerText = e.target.files[0].name;
   } 
  };
  
  inputFile.click();
}
```

```html
<div onclick="selectFile()" class="card-header bg-success">
Completada
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="21" height="21" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-camera ml-1" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
      <path d="M15 12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h1.172a3 3 0 0 0 2.12-.879l.83-.828A1 1 0 0 1 6.827 3h2.344a1 1 0 0 1 .707.293l.828.828A3 3 0 0 0 12.828 5H14a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v6zM2 4a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v6a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V6a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-1.172a2 2 0 0 1-1.414-.586l-.828-.828A2 2 0 0 0 9.172 2H6.828a2 2 0 0 0-1.414.586l-.828.828A2 2 0 0 1 3.172 4H2z" />
      <path d="M8 11a2.5 2.5 0 1 1 0-5 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 0 5zm0 1a3.5 3.5 0 1 0 0-7 3.5 3.5 0 0 0 0 7zM3 6.5a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0z" />
  </svg>
  <span id="nameFile"></span>
</div>
```

**2.- Usando un input oculto**

Colocas un `input` y lo ocultas, luego con un `label` y su atributo `for` lo activas

```css
input[type=file]{
  width:0;
  height:0:
  opacity:0:
}
```

```html
<label for="inputFile" class="card-header bg-success">
  Completado
  <input id="inputFile" type="file">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="21" height="21" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-camera ml-1" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
      <path d="M15 12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h1.172a3 3 0 0 0 2.12-.879l.83-.828A1 1 0 0 1 6.827 3h2.344a1 1 0 0 1 .707.293l.828.828A3 3 0 0 0 12.828 5H14a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v6zM2 4a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v6a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V6a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-1.172a2 2 0 0 1-1.414-.586l-.828-.828A2 2 0 0 0 9.172 2H6.828a2 2 0 0 0-1.414.586l-.828.828A2 2 0 0 1 3.172 4H2z" />
      <path d="M8 11a2.5 2.5 0 1 1 0-5 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 0 5zm0 1a3.5 3.5 0 1 0 0-7 3.5 3.5 0 0 0 0 7zM3 6.5a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0z" />
  </svg>
</label>
```

**3.- Usando [showOpenFilePicker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showOpenFilePicker)**

Ojo que como no podía ser de otra manera esta API no es compatible con firefox y tampoco no el snippet de pruebas de SOes

```js
async function selectFile(){
 let fileHandle = await window.showOpenFilePicker();
}
```

```html
<div onclick="selectFile()" class="card-header bg-success">
Completada
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="21" height="21" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-camera ml-1" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
      <path d="M15 12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V6a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h1.172a3 3 0 0 0 2.12-.879l.83-.828A1 1 0 0 1 6.827 3h2.344a1 1 0 0 1 .707.293l.828.828A3 3 0 0 0 12.828 5H14a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v6zM2 4a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v6a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V6a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-1.172a2 2 0 0 1-1.414-.586l-.828-.828A2 2 0 0 0 9.172 2H6.828a2 2 0 0 0-1.414.586l-.828.828A2 2 0 0 1 3.172 4H2z" />
      <path d="M8 11a2.5 2.5 0 1 1 0-5 2.5 2.5 0 0 1 0 5zm0 1a3.5 3.5 0 1 0 0-7 3.5 3.5 0 0 0 0 7zM3 6.5a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0z" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias Yussef me sirvió la primera opción, una duda cómo podría mostrar el nombre del archivo subido al costado de la imagen de cámara

Comment: Yussef, gracias revise el codigo me funciono. Una consulta como se puede eliminar o limpiar el contenido que trae un file cuando se carga un archivo?